# Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{[0,1]}\frac{n\cos(nx)}{1+n^2 x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-measure

I have tried several methods but even I can not calculate.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{[0,1]}\frac{n\cos(nx)}{1+n^2 x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,dx$$
If anyone can help, it was part of a test and still I can not solve.

Comment: Did you try to use dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: I think it will be $0$.

Comment: This is surprisingly tight. If I cannot easily find a dominating function for LDCT, I usually try to split the interval into $[0,\delta]$ and $[\delta,1]$, take the obvious bound on each of those intervals, use that to get a $\delta$-dependent bound on the integrals, and then optimize with respect to $\delta$. But in this situation it does not work: you get a bound of $\frac{n+n^3 \delta^{5/2}}{1+n^2 \delta^{3/2}}$, and there is no way to make $\delta$ small enough to keep the second term in the numerator small and simultaneously large enough to mitigate the first term in the numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align*} 
\frac{n \cos(nx)}{1+n^2 x^{3/2}} &\leq \frac{n}{n^2x^{3/2}} \\
&= x^{-3/2} \frac{1}{n} &&(1) \\
\end{align*}$$

Since $2ab \leq a^2+b^2$, it follows (with $a =1$ and $b=nx^{3/4}$)

$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{n \cos(nx)}{1+n^2 x^{3/2}} &\leq \frac{n}{2nx^{3/4}} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} x^{-3/4} &&(2)
\end{align*} $$
You can use this and the dominated convergence theorem to get that the limit is 0.

(1) gives you the (almost everywhere) pointwise convergence to 0.

(2) shows that the sequence is dominated by an integrable function.

Comment: $x^{-3/2}$ is not integrable...

Comment: That was careless. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$|f_n (x)|=\left|\frac{n\cos (nx) }{1+n^2 \sqrt{x^3} }\right|\leq \frac{n }{1+n^2 \sqrt{x^3} }\leq \frac{n}{2\sqrt{1\cdot n^2 \sqrt{x^3}}} =2^{-1} x^{-\frac{3}{4}}=\varphi (x)$$ and $$\int_0^1\varphi (x) dx =\int_0^1 2^{-1} x^{-\frac{3}{4}} dx =2<\infty$$
therefore the sequence $(f_n ) $ is dominated by integrable function $\varphi .$

Moreover $$f(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n (t)=\begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ for } 0<t\leq 1\\ \infty \mbox{ for } t=0\end{cases}$$
thus by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n (t)dt =\int_0^1 f(t) dt =0.$$

Comment: You might mention that you've used a named inequality, namely the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

Comment: (Alternately, this can be viewed as Young's inequality.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider, $$f(x)=\frac{n}{1+n^2x^{3/2}}.$$

Then, $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and so Riemann integrable in $[0,1]$.

So, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0$$

Comment: This is dubious because $f$ is not independent of $n.$